# Wordpress site with footer that is covering content on one page.

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I really don't know much about coding and my developer has gone dark so I really need some advice on how to fix this problem.  The footer on one of my pages won't stay at the bottom and is covering up some of the content.  Below is the code.  How can I make the footer stay at the bottom of the page?  Here is the page:  http://www.halfmoonbaymeetings.com/hot-dates-hot-rates/

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Hot Dates Hot Rates
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="col7 equalheight" id="content">
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=76'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', TRUE); if($subtitle != '') { ?>
        <p class="subtitle"><?php echo $subtitle; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1000&post_type=featured-hotels'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_hotdates', true ) ) { ?>
        <div class="col6 featuredhotel steals hotelheight">
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_hotdates", true); ?>
        </div><!-- END .col6.featuredhotel.steals -->
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- END .col8 #content -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

And here is the footer code from the Stylesheet:

.footerwrap {
background: #F9F9F9;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 100%;

}

.footerwrap .col12 { text-align: center; }

.footerwidgets {
background: #eee;
border-top: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: If it is a public page, posting a link should be helpful. And being specific on what's expected and what it is atm - would be useful.

Comment: TJ, the page is http://www.halfmoonbaymeetings.com/hot-dates-hot-rates/.  As you can see, my footer is kinda just floating there and covering up one of the promo offers.  I'm just trying to get the footer to stay at the bottom and allow me to add as many promo offers as I would like without covering them up.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say "at the bottom", do you mean "after the content" when the user scrolls or fixed to the bottom of the browser and always there, scroll or not?

Comment: Joe, when I say "at the bottom" I actually mean that it needs to sit below all the content.  I need to be able to scroll all the way to the bottom to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `margin-bottom: 289px;` to the .contentwrap div because the footer is 289px high so you need to add 289px bottom of the .contentwrap div to offset that.

```
.contentwrap 
{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 289px;
}
```

Comment: Howlin, that seemed to have pushed it to the bottom of the page, but it was still covering up the content and it messed up the margins at the bottom of the rest of the pages.  It's really odd to me that I'm only having issues with the footer covering up content on one page...

Comment: @Keith, try `margin-bottom: 578px;`

Comment: that fixed the problem on that page, but messed up all of the others by creating a bunch of extra space.  Please see here:  http://www.halfmoonbaymeetings.com/featured-hotels/

Comment: Looking at http://www.halfmoonbaymeetings.com/hot-dates-hot-rates/ that page I think the real problem is that you have the height of `col7 equalheight` set as `height: 1330px;` when it is really 1900px heigh, if you remove that height and the margin-bottom you just put in, it should be okay